# PostgreSQL User Defined Type Conversion from Oracle - CREATE TYPE <name> AS TABLE OF <type>

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types, ora2pg, postgresql-15

I've used ora2Pg to convert a PL/SQL procedure which uses a user-defined Oracle Object Types and corresponding Table Object Type.

The Object Types and the Stored Procedure convert successfully and both install/compile successfully in PostgreSQL version 15.1

However, I'm not seeing the expected behaviour when trying to assign a Object Type instance to its corresponding Table Object Type.

Using a stripped down test case to demonstrate this:

1: Oracle Object Type and corresponding Table Object Type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_myobj AS OBJECT (rid         NUMBER,
                               description VARCHAR2(100))
/

CREATE TYPE tab_myobjs AS TABLE OF t_myobj;
/
```

converts to the following PostgreSQL Object Types:

```
CREATE TYPE t_myobj AS (rid          integer,
                        description  varchar(100));

CREATE TYPE tab_myobjs AS (tab_myobjs t_myobj[]);
```

2: The converted PostgreSQL Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_prc() LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
DECLARE
  v_myobj        t_myobj;
  v_myojbs_tab   tab_myobjs;
  v_error        VARCHAR(100);

BEGIN

  RAISE NOTICE '1: START: Assign v_myobj object type attributes';
  v_myobj.rid := 1;
  v_myobj.description := 'test';

  RAISE NOTICE '2: Assign v_myobj object type to v_myojbs_tab';
  v_myojbs_tab := tab_myobjs(v_myobj);

  RAISE NOTICE '3: END';

  EXCEPTION

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;

      v_error := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,512);
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'Unhandled Exception: '||v_error USING ERRCODE = '45000';

END; $$
```

3: When I call TEST_PRC, the following is returned:

```
NOTICE:  1: START: Assign v_myobj object type attributes
NOTICE:  2: Assign v_myobj object type to v_myojbs_tab
ERROR:  Unhandled Exception: function tab_myobjs(t_myobj) does not exist
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_prc() line 24 at RAISE
```

i.e. this line **v_myojbs_tab := tab_myobjs(v_myobj);** throws the error.

My question is whether PostgreSQL actually supports usage/assignment of Table Object Types, e.g. **tab_myobjs**, and, if so, what is the syntax to assign a standard Object Type, e.g. an instance of **t_myobj** to the table type.

Thank you
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to write this in such a complicated fashion in PostgreSQL. A simple version would be:

```
CREATE TYPE t_myobj AS (rid          integer,
                        description  varchar(100));

CREATE PROCEDURE test_prc() LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$DECLARE
  v_myojbs_tab   t_myobj[];
BEGIN
  v_myojbs_tab[1] := (1, 'test');
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @laurenz. Such a simple approach compared to the ora2Pg conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that ora2pg does not support automatic conversion of plsql using custom types and /or collection types such as nested tables.